# How to put quotes around a string that has quotes?

Tags: string, swift, sprite-kit, quotes

Making a game in spritekit and I have an array of famous historical quotations. I'm having trouble adding the quotes because the syntax requires me to use quotes. For example, I want to do something like ""apple"", ""orange"", but it won't let me use double quotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let fruit = "\"apple\""
```